# Read bucket object in CDK

Tags: amazon-s3, import, terraform, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

In terraform to read an object from s3 bucket at the time of deployment I can use data source

```
data aws_s3_bucket_object { }
```

Is there a similar concept in CDK? I've seen various methods of uploading assets to s3, as well as importing an existing bucket, but not getting an object from the bucket. I need to read a configuration file from the bucket that will affect further deployment.

Comment: You can copy with `aws s3 cp ...` then read is up to you, cat, grep or use your favorite option

Comment: I am trying to avoid cli.. but this probably may be the only way.

Comment: A [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#custom-resources) may work.  CloudFormation will call the Custom Resource's backing Lambda at deploy-time.  Its job is to retrieve the configuration file with a `s3:GetObject` SDK call.  Do you need to consume the whole file, or just extract certain values?

Comment: I need to read a JSON file from given S3 key and parse it. Values from that object will affect following deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its important to remember that CDK itself is *not* a deployment option. it *can* deploy, but the code you are writing in a cdk stack is the **definition** of your resources - not a method for deployment.

So, you can do one of a few things.

1. Use your SDK for your language to make a call to the s3 bucket and load the data directly. This is perfectly acceptable and an understood way to gather information you need before deployment - each time the stack Synths (which it does before every `cdk deploy` that code will run and will pull your data.
2. Use a CodePipeline to set up a proper pipeline, and give it two sources - one your version control repo and the second your s3 bucket:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-multi-in-out.html

3. The preferred way - drop the json file, and use Parameter Store.  CDK contains modules that will create a token version of this parameter on synth, and when it deploys it will reference that properly back to the Systems Manager Parameter store

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/get_ssm_value.html

If your parameters change *after* deployment, you can have that as part of your cdk stack pretty easily (using cfn outputs). If they change in the middle/during deployment, you really need to be using a CodePipeline to manage these steps instead of just CDK.

Because remember: The cdk deploy option is just a convenience. It will execute everything and has no way to pause in the middle and execute specific steps. (other than a very basic, this depends on this resources)

Comment: It has to be a JSON in S3 because that information is used by other things besides CDK deployment. I came to the conclusion that using SDK in this scenario is probably the best compromise, so I will accept it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Parameter store can be used for a lot of different places as well, so you may want to consider looking into that for a future improvement. The only place you dont want to use it is during an actual lambda execution - the start up time to access Parameters is super slow. Fine during deployment - horrendous in production.  (if they are needed as part of a lambda, then id just push them into environment variables if not sensitive, or Secrets Manager if they are)